# Fetching new JSON data each time Javascript function is called

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a Java REST API, with some JSOn data, that I'm working with, in javascript.

I have two methods one to show data, and when to add new data:

so I have added an EventListener to my first bata to submit data:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8084/RestandJson/api/Person');
request.onload = function(){
  var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  addPerson(data);


};
request.send();

});
```

with the addPerson method like this:

```
const addPerson = (data) => {
var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
var id = data[data.length-1].id +1;
const person = {fName, lName, age, id};

data.push(person);
console.log(person);
for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
    console.log(data[i]);
}
```

}

the problem is, that new data is generated for each GET request, so I only want to fetch the data once, and save that in an array, and then add new persons from there on.

I have a method to show the JSON data as well after converting it into objects:

I added an event listener to another button like before where I'm calling this method:

```
render HTML = (data) => {
let htmlString = "";


for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    htmlString += "<p> " + data[i].fName +" " + " " + data[i].lName + " " +  data[i].age  + " " + data[i].id  + "</p>"
}
root.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//bind click event on button to add person info
addPersonbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addPerson();
});


// fetch all person data from api (call this function when app load)
function getPersonList() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8084/RestandJson/api/Person');
    request.onload = function(){
      var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        renderHTML(data);
    };
    request.send();
}

function postPersonData(personInfo) {
    // your api to add single persion info

    // on success call getPersonList(), it will update the list 
}

const addPerson = () => {
var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
//var id = data[data.length-1].id +1;    // handle it on db side, Primary key, auto generation
const person = {fName, lName, age};
postPersonData(person);

}

renderHTML = (data) => {
let htmlString = "";
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    htmlString += "<p> " + data[i].fName +" " + " " + data[i].lName + " " +  data[i].age  + " " + data[i].id  + "</p>"
}
root.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
}
```

i have made pseudo code for you , hope it will helps you a little bit

Comment: This is very good thank you, however, if I test it out, be getting more people the person added, is never shown. And i keep getting new values each time, is it possible to get a single array from one GET request, instead of new data each time?

Comment: is it possible to get a single array from one GET request, instead of new data each time - Yes , you can store result in a global variable* and use it.